# Shimano FCm360 28-38-48 175mm, crank can be mounted on a axis length of 118mm?

Tags: shimano, crankset

I would like to ask something.
Now, i have a 28-38-48 170mm crank KRG Burchel with 118mm/68mm monobloc.
Shimano FCm360 28-38-48 175mm, crank can be mounted on a axis length of this? (118mm). I have 13-26 8 speed (rear).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

si.shimano.com is a great source for technical documents and information on Shimano parts.
I think by "monobloc" you mean a "cartridge bottom bracket". I can't quickly find anything about a Shimano FC-M360, but the FC-M361 crankset document https://si.shimano.com/api/publish/storage/pdf/en/si/0094A/SI-0094A-001-ENG.pdf shows the FC-M361 uses a BB-UN26 (or compatible) bottom bracket with spindle length of 123 mm. The current line of Shimano square taper BBs is the BB-UN300 series, which has a 68x123 model.